# Parse HTML that is stored in a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I am parsing a group of post on a blog.
I have some HTML that I successfully assigned to a string. I am trying to get the HTML to display in a UITableview. However, I want it formatted.
For instance I want `<br />` to actually do a line break in the table and `<img scr=` to actually display the picture. How can I accomplish this.

Comment: Having HTML in an `NSString` is an error in the first place. Where do all the people come from that mix up binary buffers with strings.

Comment: I am parsing a huge XML file. All elements but this one contain plain text. There for in my parserDidFindText method I have it set into an NSMutableString.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever ever ever use UIWebView in UITableView. It won't end well.

You should check out the Three20 project's TTStyledTextLabel, which will do some basic HTML formatting. I have used it with good results in the past.